# How to use native android file-open-dialog in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I've seen this dialog to pick/open a file on android in some apps and it seems to me as the native one. But I can't find a way to use it in my own apps. The language of the attached screenshot is German, but I'm sure someone will recognize it. [Screenshot of the file-dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yApNt.jpg) 
 .in Unity3d its possible open native file Dialog in game with Unity3d c# code?
Thanks for your guide. (sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem and I want to guide others who have this problem
Go to the site below and use the free plugin.
[**Unity Native Gallery Plugin**](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeGallery)